# Inserting rows to dataframe on multiple indices based on conditions in python-pandas

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

[image]

Whenever I see an instance where start is followed by stop **and** DURATION column is 0, I need to insert a row after that (at 4th and 8th row in this case), which should contain pretty much the same values of its previous row, but the event column should be denoted by E1.

I need to get something like this

[image]

How can I achieve this since multiple indices can have the values with START-STOP and duration as 0?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide your data example as text

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a sequence 'start-stop' (stop is always followed by start), it will work:

```
df.loc[(df['DURATION'] == 0) & (df['event'] == 'stop'), 'event'] = 'E1'
```

What means: Put 'E1' in column 'event' for each row which has 0 in column 'DURATION' and 'stop' in column 'event'.